# Can you preview the effects of a command?

Tags: 12.04, bash

How can you preview the effects of a command? For instance, if I want to run `rm -r ./*`, or `chown -r ./*`. Is it possible to run a safe "test" of that command with the ability to ensure that nothing stupid was happening before I ran it?

Answer (score 1):

For a safe guard use following commands to see the preview

```
echo ./*
ls -la ./*
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know I can help you with rm command. It'dhhaving some feature like interaction before action.

Syntax is

```
    rm -i /path /to /file
```

So when ever you would like to delete that file it will ask confirmation from you.